# Have offcanvas overlap content instead of pushing it

Tags: jquery, css

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54191672/theme/index.html

Resize the browser to 1000px.

When clicking on the menu icon, I'm trying to have the sidebar overlap the content instead of pushing the content to the right. I thought setting it to a position absolute would work but then the menu's height is reset and the width messes up.

CSS:

```
.sidebar {
    background: #fff;
    padding-top: 65px;
    padding-left: 40px; 
    width: 15%;
    position: relative;
}

.sidr {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 999999;
    width: 260px;
    overflow-x: none;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I'm using the plugin Sidr for the offcanvas functionality.

How can I have the offcanvas sidebar overlap instead of push?